# unepected change of order status by ipn

Tags: magento, paypal-ipn

Why is order status changed to complete twice (the second change is triggered by ipn)?
Is it standard magento behaviour? Does it seem strange to have 2 complete complete order statuses?
How to solve this prolem? Last 2 status in order history don't seem correct, right?

Here'are last status for order:

```
Sep 29, 2014 3:04:06 AM|Complete
Customer Notified  
Sep 29, 2014 3:04:06 AM|Processing
Customer Notification Not Applicable 
IPN "Completed". Registered notification about captured amount of $50.00. Transaction ID: "6RE84821N9702243S".
Sep 29, 2014 3:03:57 AM|Complete
Customer Notified
```

I think the magento changes to complete once the payment is made, and then when ipn is received.
Is it a bug of magento or not?

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes when the ipn call comes after the customer has been correctly redirected to the website. I never experienced it with paypal but seen it with a french payment solution. I would advise you to check that the customer is really not notified twice because that can be a bit annoying.

Comment: when ipn is received, order status is complete. But core magento code from Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn changes status for some reason. Why does it happen? Maybe I don't understand anything, but this behaviour doesn't seen correct to me. How to avoid this issue?

Comment: I am really not a specialist of paypal ipn but the idea is that once a payment is received, paypal launch ipn call and at that moment, Magento checks the order as complete. It normally happens before the customer is redirected. If not, you see the processing state between. The delay can come from the server (yours or paypal's). To avoid that, you can set a delay before redirecting the customer to be sure that everything is done. It is all the knowledge I have on that.